# How to enable wifi when the hardware switch doesn't work

Tags: wireless, internet, hardware

On my acer aspire 5020 laptop the turn on wifi button is greyed out. And I've tried pressing the hardware wireless button and nothing happens. Is there any other ways of turning wifi on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: 06:05.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0013] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GN-WIAG02 [1458:e911]
        Kernel driver in use: ath5k                                                                                                                                                               so hard blocked is off which is good
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no

Comment: also how to you make the code appear in a grey box

Comment: wait just out of nowhere the wifi started working. the box was no longer greyed out and i could turn wifi on. did that command do something or did i accidentally make it work

Comment: No, that command did not change anything.